# Трудности с stdin и stdout

Tags: python, sys

### Проблемы с порядком выполнения stdin и stdout

Здраствуйте, у меня есть маленький код.
Но возникла проблема в том что `sys.stdout.write()`
выполняется после `sys.stdin.read()`

```py
import sys

def register():
    sys.stdout.write("Please enter password:")
    sys.stdin.read(1)
```

**Использую:** `sys.stdin.read()` и `sys.stdout.write()`
для того чтобы при вызове функции из другого файла
все ровно всё выводилось в консоль.

Comment: `sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: Вставьте `sys.stdout.flush()` в середину.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую. Изменено: **Действительно работает, спасибо за помощь**